# How to pass state to component React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, navigator

I am new to React Native and really cant figure out why I am not able to pass a state from one component to another

```
export default class questions extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        name: "stupidCount",
        val: 1}            
}

render(){
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    const { name2 } = this.state;
    return(
        <View style={styles.box}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('Question1',  stupidCount={name2})} >
                <Text style={styles.h1}> Question 1 </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

Second component, 'Question1'

```
export default class Question2 extends Component {
render(){
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    console.log(stupidCount.val);
    return(
        <View style={styles.box}>
            <Text style={styles.h1}>Question 2 </Text>
            <Text> state test {stupidCount.val}</Text>
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: where do you get `name2` state ? cause i just see `name` in your state :)

Answer (score 6):

I think you are using `react-navigation`.
If yes, then the following changes need to made to access value of `stupidCount` in Question2 component.

In `questions` component,

state should be set as:

```
this.state={
  stupidCount: 1,
}
```

onPress should be handled as

`onPress={() => navigate('Question1',  { stupidCount: this.state.stupidCount } )}`

and in Questions2 component, you can access the value as:

`this.props.navigation.state.params.stupidCount`